# How to capture video from webcam on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to capture a video from the webcam while my Unity application is running. Right now I can get the webcam and see the image with this code, but how I capture the video and save it to the disk?

```
public class captureVideo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private UnityEngine.UI.RawImage _rawImage;

    void Start()
    {
        WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;

        // for debugging purposes, prints available devices to the console
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++)
        {
            print("Webcam available: " + devices[i].name);
        }

        WebCamTexture tex = new WebCamTexture(devices[0].name);
        this._rawImage.texture = tex;
        tex.Play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, the Unity Video Capture documentation contains just such a function. Try this out! https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/VR.WSA.WebCam.VideoCapture.html

Comment: I have tried this one, but the webcam does not initialize on the editor =/

Comment: So you want to record the screen while in the Unity Editor? Can you just capture the entire screen using this:  https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-unity-recorder/?tab=overview#6000f436edbc2a3c53b3d804   You can set up a 'Targeted Camera' and make that Camera the one you want to record. If it is pointed at the image on the screen that represents the WebCam, you can record just that. Of course, for an ingame solution, you  need something else, I guess we need to know more about your motivations! ;)

Comment: Actually I made it work with the solution that you linked, the problem was the version that I was using. But right now it's returning this error: "The VideoCapture is not in the correct state to stop recording video.". I am executing the same script of the docs.